KeyError: '__version__' installing openai-whisper on Python 3.13
Getting this error when I try to download Whisper
Python version 3.13 -
I wasted a lot of time figuring out the problem - can anyone help? I even tried reverting to a lower version but didn't help.
Collecting openai-whisper
  Using cached openai-whisper-20240930.tar.gz (800 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      <string>:5: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/pinjalim/Dropbox/Projects/Transcripto/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "/Users/pinjalim/Dropbox/Projects/Transcripto/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/pinjalim/Dropbox/Projects/Transcripto/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/q5/r66rvlp92fn06jqmhpg3zbwm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jhoypdd0/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 333, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/q5/r66rvlp92fn06jqmhpg3zbwm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jhoypdd0/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 303, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "/private/var/folders/q5/r66rvlp92fn06jqmhpg3zbwm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jhoypdd0/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 521, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/q5/r66rvlp92fn06jqmhpg3zbwm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-jhoypdd0/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 319, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 11, in read_version
      KeyError: '__version__'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.


This is a packaging bug. Report it to OpenAI, not to us.

...indeed, someone already submitted a fix, they just haven't merged it yet: https://github.com/openai/whisper/pull/2409; however, that PR notes that whisper's dependency chain also has other components that don't support Python 3.13 yet, so in general it's just plain not supported for now.

BTW, might I ask why you're trying? If you think you'll get a performance benefit from running without the GIL... there are very sound reasons that's only an experimental feature for now; consider it something that exists so library authors can work on compatibility, not actually ready for use. And for whisper, you don't need it -- any AI and numeric computing software written by remotely competent people, whisper included, already releases the GIL while it's working (by way of having the heavy lifting implemented in a non-Python language; that's a big part of why whisper uses numba)

The specific bug this question was asked about is fixed by the as-yet-unmerged PR openai/whisper#2409.
However, as of the date when that PR was filed, numba didn't support Python 3.13 either; because whisper depends on numba, this means that even with the setup.py / version.py issue corrected, one still cannot use whisper with Python 3.13.
As of present date, numba support for Python 3.13 merged to numba main three days ago; however, this is not yet included in any published release: the latest release of numba is from mid-June, and does not contain this fix.
Consequently, as of today, whisper cannot be used on Python 3.13 using only released, supported versions of its dependency chain.

Downgrading python to 3.11.9 worked. As per the OpenAI Whisper documentation they only support till version 3.11.9
